# HttpWebRequest is very slow without proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I wrote this code to read data from an external url.

`request.GetResponse()` takes more than a minute to run and is very slow.

```
string responseContent;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://payroll/PayrollReport/getPaymentHistory?number=13990701&reason=21&username=8062122&Credential=E5ohh/BZDBWAQBE2R8tmbUSiVGJ2/ndI3AmqDiCMBylOIK/eAdRZog==");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy(); // null;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            responseContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But when call this url with post man is very fast and run less than 1000ms.

[image]

In network capture only location property is different between c# and post man

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please help me slow down code execution

Comment: Use Fiddler to compare the requests. We don't know what's happening on your network nor on the payroll server. Also, if you have probably found the culprit, namely that Postman uses a proxy, which is fast, and your code doesn't, which is slow, why don't you want to use the proxy? Or is your actual question _"How to find the system default proxy"_?

Comment: This is a networking question.  We can't know why *your network* causes delays if no proxy is used. You can't fix this from code, you have to ask your network administrator for the correct settings. I'd say they **explicitly** built their network so that only the proxy has a fast outbound connection

Comment: If connections are faster with a proxy, why don't you use a proxy?

Comment: `only location property is different` that's not "just". What you posted shows a redirection to a different URL, including what looks like a session parameter. Once again this has nothing to do with HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1` to the code and the problem was solved.

> The AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 querystring is added automatically
> by ASP.NET during the cookie support detection phase. Since cookieless
> attribute in the web.config file is set to "AutoDetect", the ASP.NET
> runtime tries to detect whether the user's browser supports cookies,
> and the querystring parameter is added during that process. If cookies
> are supported, the Session ID is kept in a cookie, and if not the
> Session ID is sent in the Url of all future requests by that user.

```
Uri target = new Uri("http://payroll/PayrollReport/getPaymentHistory?number=13990701&reason=21&username=8062122&Credential=E5ohh/BZDBWAQBE2R8tmbUSiVGJ2/ndI3AmqDiCMBylOIK/eAdRZog==");

string responseContent;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();         
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport", "1") { Domain = target.Host });

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            responseContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```